# Extending admin index.html template

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have downloaded the following templates from admin.contrib: base.html, base_site.html and index.html.

I would like to extend index.html, but no matter what I do it does not seem to work.

In settings.py, I have declared the name of my app to override the order in which the admin files are render. So, I can edit the actual files and content does change when I run the server.

But, I create a file in the directory templates/admin/foo.html.

The code with foo.html is:

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}

{% block something %}
<p>Hello</p>
{% endblock %}
```

And I have change the file templates/admin/index.html to have `{% block something %}{% end block %}`

When I run the server, the content of foo.html does not display.

Do I need to add foo.html to my urls.py and create a function within views.py to render the content?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo.html` is not recognized by Django admin. If you want to customize `admin/index.html`, do your changes in `admin/index.html`.

If you want to use a separate file, include it inside the `admin/index.html` like this:

```
{% include "foo.html" %}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this does work. Am I able to use a function with views.py to load data into "foo.html"? I want "foo.html" to display some data and also have a form where I can submit data.

Comment: That's an entirely different question and we don't have enough details about it. If you post what exactly you are trying to accomplish, with all those views and data you want inside the admin, we could take a look

Comment: I want to still have the default functionality of the Django admin. However on the “main” admin page I would like to display a specific entry from my database. The specific entry will need to be checked against a few conditions. I am assuming this would have to be done within a function of the views.py file. The problem I face is passing this to “foo.html”. I could make an AJAX call when admin page loads and populate the page using jquery but I would prefer to use Django templating to do this. I hope this explains what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @CallumOsborn I believe AJAX is the way to go in this case.